# Does any manufacturer make a fused 240 V 60 A steel AC disconnect with GFCI receptacle?

Tags: electrical, hvac, switch, gfci

I need a fused pullout 240 V 60A steel AC disconnect rated at 10 horse power with a built in GFCI receptacle for use as a convenience outlet required by 2020 NEC, but cannot find one available. Has anyone heard of a manufacturer who makes one? Can you provide a model number?

I know this sounds like I am simply and self-centeredly seeking help shopping for something. That may be partially true, but mostly it is not. I have spent days and days searching for such an AC disconnect to replace the non-fused one I already purchased that had a GFCI receptacle built-in, then discovered that I need extra fuses to bridge a low SCCR device and a much higher AFC that can appear at its inputs should a fault occur. I know I can use a current limiting fuse for this situation, but cannot find a fusible disconnect with a GFCI receptacle to put them in. I did find one that exactly met my needs that Siemens makes, but no matter where among the many places I looked (except for an abused one on eBay) every seller said "out of stock." I've been spinning my wheels going around in circles and thought that maybe someone might have been there and done that, or may have used one such as I describe and knows which company makes one.

Also, I realize there is a strong general feeling among electricians that putting a GFCI receptacle inside an AC disconnect isn't what they would recommend or do. I accept that they have their reasons for feeling that way, maybe it seems like too much extra work to ask of them, but I have spent a large amount of time thinking about having this option and see good reasons to have a convenience 120 V GFCI outlet inside the disconnect, and especially so considering the design of the model I did purchase from MARS that permits two plug cords to be plugged in and still be able to close the disconnect door. It's a well designed product. Unfortunately they do not seem to make the fusible version, else I would have purchased it.

On a large distributor's website, I checked the manufacturer with the greatest selection of AC Disconnects, Siemens. They had 25 different AC Disconnects listed, and 36% of those listed now have GFCI receptacles built-in. I think that proves that I am not crazy wanting to have a GFCI receptacle in the disconnect. One of those met my needs, but it is the one I had been scouring the earth trying to find in stock somewhere.

Comment: Doubt that any code allows a convenience outlet on a 60 amp circuit without it's own 15/20 amp breaker/circuit(sub panel).

Comment: @crip659 You are correct. I bought a well designed disconnect (MARS) that has a GFCI receptacle built-in. It's on its own 15A circuit, so there are two branch circuits involved. I love the way that enclosure is designed to have the receptacle up top at an angle, so it is protected from rain, and two plug cord plastic channels help the wires escape at the bottom so you can close the door with the power tools plugged in. I believe the 2020 NEC requires a convenience outlet be near such equipment, but doesn't require it be IN the disconnect. I just happen to be enthralled with the MARS design.

Comment: "Out of stock" is a common refrain heard all around the world these days and doesn't justify a shopping question, no matter how much searching you've already done.

Answer (score 3):

Typically, the mandatory A/C service receptacle is fed from a different and unrelated circuit.  Usually this is an "outdoor outlet" circuit that is already there, and already has GFCI protection.

---

There is no requirement of any kind whatsoever that the 120V convenience receptacle be on the same circuit as the A/C.  In fact, that makes it stupid, because

- you need to run a neutral, so 50% more cost for the wire.
- you're gonna need a subpanel there since the mandatory outlet can't be on a >20A circuit.

The normal approach to this problem is to simply make sure the existing outdoor receptacle circuit has an outlet near the A/C unit.

I suppose if someone were hell bent for leather to have *one circuit* to the A/C site, they could use an RV subpanel, which provides a 3-4 space micro-panel and space for a GFCI receptacle.

---

Further, there is no requirement for any receptacle to be GFCI.  Equipment located elsewhere (e.g. indoors) can provide the GFCI protection to the receptacle.  This is all the more reason to use a separate circuit, since providing GFCI protection to grounded, hardwired A/C units is a waste of safety money.

The A/C service receptacle does not need to be on a dedicated circuit or any special circuit (it just can't be on a circuit it's not allowed on, such as a bathroom receptacle or EVSE circuit.)

Comment: I have two outdoor receptacles, at the far other end of the house - GFCI. Built in 1997. Vintage GE load center mounted on outside wall; difficult/very expensive to find GFCI/AFCI breakers. All original CBs 1/2", all newer ones, when they can be found, are 1". NEC 210.8(A)(3) requires all 125 V receptacles installed outdoors to be GFCI protected. Receptacle will be separate 15 A circuit. I could not find 40 A GFCI bkr for the HVAC, which is VFD, which frequently causes nuisance tripping. 8/26/21 TIA pushed off requirement for GFCI on this HVAC till 2023, about power conversion equipment.

Comment: @Guiermo Holy smoke, man, you are "lost in Code" like John Nash.  Many strong ideas, little understanding.  This is causing zero progress and self-defeat.  This is an easy job for a professional who has a clear head about the problem set.  Putting GFCI/AFCI **protection** off legacy panels is easy, hooking up a 40A hardwired A/C is easy, dealing with legacy GE panels is easy, but you are getting in your own way for some reason.